# What's the name of the feature in Unity that allows windows to be tiled on the left and right sides of the screen?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, unity, compiz

In Unity, when you drag title bar of window, and point it to left side or right one it maximizes to half screen (full height, half width).

What's the name of this feature? How to install it on 10.10 without upgrading to 11.04 so that I can see two window side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the Compiz Grid plugin.  On Ubuntu 10.10, I believe you need to install [compiz-fusion-plugins-extra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra) [image: Install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra]; it can then be configured using

**CompizConfig Settings Manager → Grid → Edges → Resize Actions**

The defaults in Ubuntu 11.04 involve Upper Left Corner, Left Edge, and Lower Left Corner being set to Left Half, and Upper Right Corner, Right Edge, and Lower Right Corner being set to Right Half.

Comment: thanks,... this is what i want... but how can i put a window to left corner just by draghing and point to left screen ?? i hope this could be.. it's easier..

Comment: Set Left Edge to Top Left Corner or Bottom Left Corner in the configuration dialog I suggested?  If that's not it, I'm not quite understanding your question.

Comment: i mean.. how to set window in left grid just by dragging the titlebar,.. how i do now is press combination key `super + left` (like unity, or win7 does)

Comment: As far as I know, that's what the directions I gave you do, although I confess that I don't have an Ubuntu 10.10 installation on a suitable system to test.